# Rendering equation - Vectorization of computations

Tags: python, matrix, computer-vision, vectorization

I have this Irradiance equation : `**E = n*M*n^T**', with n^T equals to n transposed.

Where:

```
n: normal map of size (BxHxWxC), B=batch_size,H=height, W=width, C=3=Color channels.
M: 4x4 Matrix, one for each channel, so I guess it's Bx4x4x3
```

How can I vectorize the aforementioned equation in order to get irradiance in shape : `BxHxWxC?`